# Error: Creating a <View> each loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to display a JSON, shown on the link below:

> https://api.myjson.com/bins/ur1k

When I loop over it:

```
renderList(data) {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
return(
data.map((singleData) => {
  return Object.keys(singleData).map((key) => {
    return(
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>{key}- {singleData[key]}</Text>
      </View>
      )
  })
})
)
}
```

...

```
row: {
 flexDirection: 'row',
 height: 60,
 borderBottomWidth: 1,
 borderColor: 'black',
 justifyContent: 'space-between',
 alignItems: 'center',
 padding: 20
}
```

...

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: [],
  }
}

componentWillMount(){
  api.getIsisData().then((response) =>{
    this.setState({
      data: response.result.data,
      key: '',
      values: []
    })
  })
}
```

The simulator is working like the image below:
[image]

But I'd like to display like shown below:

[image]

Where am I getting wrong in the loop?

Comment: What do you mean with *"like the JSON is formatted"*?

Comment: show us an example of how you want us to display it

Comment: @AKADER example on the description. Thanks, bro

Comment: To get "json formatted" stuff, return the object collection as is. Set content-type="application/json"

Comment: @celerno i think i didn't explained correctly. I'd like to display that way on the bottom of the description.

Comment: use a `foreach` loop on your `result.data` inside of the `<Text>`

Comment: @AKADER trying to do with 'foreach'

Comment: `for(var i =0;i < result.data.length;i++)
{//do something with result.data[i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My answer**

I just created a 'rows' array to get each line of each object and rendered on the view.

```
renderList(data) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
  return(
    data.map((singleData) => {
      var rows = []
      Object.keys(singleData).map((key,index) => {
        rows.push(<Text>{key} - {singleData[key]}</Text>)
      })
      return(
        <View style={styles.row}>
          {rows}
        </View>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(var i =0;i < result.data.length;i++) {
       for(var key in result.data[i]{
             //do somethying with key}
    }
}
```

you can append it to a state variable and place it all in a formated `<View>`

Comment: How can I get a variable in react using a for, like I used with map() or better how can i append it on a state variable?

Comment: the setState would be inside the 'for'?

Comment: You need to start fresh. Take the time to look over how state works in React

Comment: @RaphaelOnofre Putting the setState() inside the for-loop is a very bad idea. Like AKADER suggested, take some time to read how the state works as well as read about a component's lifecycle.

Comment: @Giorgos this app has one screen which it will be mounted on the componentWillMount(), and then displayed. I'm setting the state there. I've update the problem description with the state and the componentWillMount() stuff.